# Presenting a view in fullscreen not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to present a view that is showd from the bottom to the top. This is my code

```
let myPageViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myPageViewControllerID") as! MyPageViewController
myPageViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myPageViewController)
navigationController?.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Despite I am using `.fullScreen`, the view is not presented on full screen. 
I tried using peformSegue to show the view with this code

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "myPageViewSegue", sender: nil)
```

the page is presented on fullscreen but from the left to the right and not from the bottom to the top.

The third code I tried is this one

```
let detailVC = MyPageViewController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailVC)
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(detailVC, animated: true)
```

here I get an error `Application tried to present modally an active controller`. I tried to add self.dismiss when disappearing MyPageViewController but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 11):

The problem maybe is you are not presenting navigationController you are presenting detail vc, Use this

```
'let detailVC = MyPageViewController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailVC)
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(navigationController, animated: true)'
```

if problem still exists use

```
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

Comment: How to make sure this never goes unnoticed?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
let detailVC = MyPageViewController()
detailVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(detailVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, worked for me:

Setup up your segue:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "myPageViewSegue", sender: self)
```

Then use the prepare for segue method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destVC = segue.destination as! MyPageViewSegue
    destVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and was stumped. Then I realized that overriding `dismiss` also overrides `.fullscreen`

```
// This breaks .fullscreen
override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
  super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
  // do something
}
```

It's clear that you don't need this if `.fullscreen` is being used, but leaving it in place caused problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code with below lines and then Booom work like a charm

```
let vc = MyPageViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let detailVC = MyPageViewController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailVC)
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
present(detailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Explanation:
Its very simple. Its better to explain it line by line. Line 1: Declare the viewcontroller. Line 2: Add Navigation Controller (its optional. If you don't need, then you may skip navigation bar). Line 3: We have defined the modal presentation style link as overCurrentContext. and present the navigationController (it will come up with navigation bar and viewcontroller) or only the viewcontroller as per your need. In this piece of code, you will get the viewcontroller without navigation bar.

Comment: Can you please add an explanation of what this does and how it does it to your answer? Thank you.

Comment: Its very simple. Its better to explain it line by line. Line 1: Declare the viewcontroller. Line 2: Add Navigation Controller (its optional. If you don't need, then you may skip navigation bar). Line 3: We have defined the modal presentation style [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621355-modalpresentationstyle) as overCurrentContext. and present the navigationController (it will come up with navigation bar and viewcontroller) or only the viewcontroller as per your need. In this piece of code, you will get the viewcontroller without navigation bar.

Comment: Please *add that to your answer*.